# git: fatal: Not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /cygdrive/s)

Tags: git

I have a Win10 laptop with git 2.8.3, and a Win Vista Desktop with git 1.6.x.x.
Both machines have a git repo, and a network share allows me to git-pull changes from one machine to the other, allowing easy sync, backup, or grab-and-hit-the-road.

When I updated from Win7 to Win10 on the laptop, however, the git-pull executed on the laptop failed with not-a-git-repo (tried via both windows cmd prompt and bash). Interestingly enough, there is no error when I use git gui.

As far as I can tell, no damage has occurred to either repo (git gui suggests this is true because it not only does not complain, but successfully did the fetch and merge).

I can walk to the desktop, cd via the network share to the laptop repo, and type 'git status'. It works.

If I do the reverse, from the laptop keyboard I cd to the desktop and do a git status, it fails (not a git repo). How can that be? Walk to the actual desktop to that repo, no problem: add, rm, commit, etc.

I then went from the laptop keyboard, via the share, to the desktop repo and created a scrap file in the repo on the desktop. Then I walked over to the desktop and confirmed that the scrap file is, indeed there. This confirms that I am actually working in the correct repo, and that I have create and delete privs there (home network, my computers, full control for both the share and the folders, so shouldn't be an issue, but this confirms probably true).

Everything seems to me that my repo is valid and accessible, but it doesn't work. Is there any way to find out exactly what's wrong, in my *particular* case, when git claims not-a-repo?

I appreciate any advice.

Comment: Does the git gui that you're using, use its own instance of git, or the system git (ie, 2.8.3 that you run from cmd/bash)?

Comment: Can you clone the repo?

Comment: Have you checked if you can access the `.git/` folder in the repository from the laptop?
**And** is `git` still working on the laptop? e.g. try `git init example-repo`

Comment: git gui - from Shawn Pearce, et al. Says git-gui version 0.20.GITGUI; git version 2.9.2.windows.1. So, I think it has its own git built in, but don't know (from cmd prompt, git --version reports 2.8.3).

Comment: Animi: the .git/ folder on both the desktop and the laptop are accessible to each other, as are the files within. Each machine has its own repo, and all machine-local functions, such as add, rm, and status, work as expected. If I sit at the desktop, and cd to the laptop via the share, then perform a git status, that works fine. If I sit at the laptop and cd to the desktop via the share, then perform the git status, that fails. I do not know why, but feel that is at the heart of my problem.

Comment: VonC: Good question. Yes, I can clone the laptop repo on the laptop, and I can clone the desktop repo on the desktop.   ###    I can also git-pull to the laptop from the cloned copy on the desktop (but not the original copy on the desktop).    ###   Something you said made me think disk error, so I did a chkdsk, which did find and fix an error; I doubt it was related to my problem - I can do both a git-clone and a git-pull to the new repo on the desktop from the old, and the laptop can access the new repo on the desktop (git-pull, git-status) but not the old.

Comment: Is it possible for a repo to be corrupted such that it fails for a git pull/fetch from one source, but works in every other way (pull/fetches, status, etc.) from other sources and with gui-git?  ###   Seems magical to me; I wish there were better diagnostics and tracing here. It's already cost me more time than it would have taken to add a separate useful diagnostic for each possible fail condition.